# How to find the shortest dependency path between two words in Python?

Tags: python, nltk, text-parsing

I try to find the dependency path between two words in Python given dependency tree.

For sentence

> Robots in popular culture are there to remind us of the awesomeness of
>   unbound human agency.

I used practnlptools (https://github.com/biplab-iitb/practNLPTools) to get the dependency parsing result like:

```
nsubj(are-5, Robots-1)
xsubj(remind-8, Robots-1)
amod(culture-4, popular-3)
prep_in(Robots-1, culture-4)
root(ROOT-0, are-5)
advmod(are-5, there-6)
aux(remind-8, to-7)
xcomp(are-5, remind-8)
dobj(remind-8, us-9)
det(awesomeness-12, the-11)
prep_of(remind-8, awesomeness-12)
amod(agency-16, unbound-14)
amod(agency-16, human-15)
prep_of(awesomeness-12, agency-16)
```

which can also be visualized as (picture taken from https://demos.explosion.ai/displacy/)
[image]

The path length between "robots" and "are" is 1, the path length between "robots" and "awesomeness" would be 4.

My question is given above dependency parse result, how can I get dependency path or dependency path length between two words?

From my current search result, would nltk's ParentedTree help?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Sean, How can I get a similar tree structure for a sentence using nltk? I currently don't have any Grammer, and using the 'treebank' grammar, gives me error of some words not present in production list. Thank you.

Comment: @skadoosh Acutally, using NLTK getting such a nice presentation is hard. I suggest using Spacy.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your problem can easily be conceived as a graph problem where we have to find the shortest path between two nodes.

To convert your dependency parse in a graph, we first have to deal with the fact that it comes as a string. You want to get this:

```
'nsubj(are-5, Robots-1)\nxsubj(remind-8, Robots-1)\namod(culture-4, popular-3)\nprep_in(Robots-1, culture-4)\nroot(ROOT-0, are-5)\nadvmod(are-5, there-6)\naux(remind-8, to-7)\nxcomp(are-5, remind-8)\ndobj(remind-8, us-9)\ndet(awesomeness-12, the-11)\nprep_of(remind-8, awesomeness-12)\namod(agency-16, unbound-14)\namod(agency-16, human-15)\nprep_of(awesomeness-12, agency-16)'
```

to look like this:

```
[('are-5', 'Robots-1'), ('remind-8', 'Robots-1'), ('culture-4', 'popular-3'), ('Robots-1', 'culture-4'), ('ROOT-0', 'are-5'), ('are-5', 'there-6'), ('remind-8', 'to-7'), ('are-5', 'remind-8'), ('remind-8', 'us-9'), ('awesomeness-12', 'the-11'), ('remind-8', 'awesomeness-12'), ('agency-16', 'unbound-14'), ('agency-16', 'human-15'), ('awesomeness-12', 'agency-16')]
```

This way you can feed the tuple list to a graph constructor from the [networkx](http://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/overview.html) module that will analyze the list and build a graph for you, plus give you a neat method that gives you the length of the shortest path between two given nodes.

**Necessary imports**

```
import re
import networkx as nx
from practnlptools.tools import Annotator
```

**How to get your string in the desired tuple list format**

```
annotator = Annotator()
text = """Robots in popular culture are there to remind us of the awesomeness of unbound human agency."""
dep_parse = annotator.getAnnotations(text, dep_parse=True)['dep_parse']

dp_list = dep_parse.split('\n')
pattern = re.compile(r'.+?\((.+?), (.+?)\)')
edges = []
for dep in dp_list:
    m = pattern.search(dep)
    edges.append((m.group(1), m.group(2)))
```

**How to build the graph**

```
graph = nx.Graph(edges)  # Well that was easy
```

**How to compute shortest path length**

```
print(nx.shortest_path_length(graph, source='Robots-1', target='awesomeness-12'))
```

This script will reveal that the shortest path given the dependency parse is actually of length 2, since you can get from `Robots-1` to `awesomeness-12` by going through `remind-8`

```
1. xsubj(remind-8, Robots-1) 
2. prep_of(remind-8, awesomeness-12)
```

If you don't like this result, you might want to think about filtering some dependencies, in this case not allow the `xsubj` dependency to be added to the graph.

Answer (score 15):

HugoMailhot's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32895132/395857) is great. I'll write something similar for [spacy](https://spacy.io/) users who want to  find the shortest dependency path between two words (whereas HugoMailhot's answer relies on [practNLPTools](https://github.com/biplab-iitb/practNLPTools)).

The sentence:

> Robots in popular culture are there to remind us of the awesomeness of
>   unbound human agency.

has the [following dependency tree](https://demos.explosion.ai/displacy/?text=Robots%20in%20popular%20culture%20are%20there%20to%20remind%20us%20of%20the%20awesomeness%20of%20unbound%20human%20agency.&model=en&cpu=1&cph=1):

[image]

Here is the code to  find the shortest dependency path between two words:

```
import networkx as nx
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en')

# https://spacy.io/docs/usage/processing-text
document = nlp(u'Robots in popular culture are there to remind us of the awesomeness of unbound human agency.', parse=True)

print('document: {0}'.format(document))

# Load spacy's dependency tree into a networkx graph
edges = []
for token in document:
    # FYI https://spacy.io/docs/api/token
    for child in token.children:
        edges.append(('{0}-{1}'.format(token.lower_,token.i),
                      '{0}-{1}'.format(child.lower_,child.i)))

graph = nx.Graph(edges)

# https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/algorithms.shortest_paths.html
print(nx.shortest_path_length(graph, source='robots-0', target='awesomeness-11'))
print(nx.shortest_path(graph, source='robots-0', target='awesomeness-11'))
print(nx.shortest_path(graph, source='robots-0', target='agency-15'))
```

Output:

```
4
['robots-0', 'are-4', 'remind-7', 'of-9', 'awesomeness-11']
['robots-0', 'are-4', 'remind-7', 'of-9', 'awesomeness-11', 'of-12', 'agency-15']
```

To install spacy and networkx:

```
sudo pip install networkx 
sudo pip install spacy
sudo python -m spacy.en.download parser # will take 0.5 GB
```

Some benchmarks regarding spacy's dependency parsing: https://spacy.io/docs/api/

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This answer relies on Stanford CoreNLP to obtain the dependency tree of a sentence. It borrows quite some code from HugoMailhot's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32895132/395857) when using networkx.

Before running the code, one needs to:

1. `sudo pip install pycorenlp` (python interface for Stanford CoreNLP)
2. Download [Stanford CoreNLP](http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP)
3. Start a Stanford CoreNLP server as follows:

   ```
   java -mx4g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer -port 9000 -timeout 50000
   ```

Then one can run the following code to find the shortest dependency path between two words:

```
import networkx as nx
from pycorenlp import StanfordCoreNLP
from pprint import pprint

nlp = StanfordCoreNLP('http://localhost:{0}'.format(9000))
def get_stanford_annotations(text, port=9000,
                             annotators='tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,depparse,parse'):
    output = nlp.annotate(text, properties={
        "timeout": "10000",
        "ssplit.newlineIsSentenceBreak": "two",
        'annotators': annotators,
        'outputFormat': 'json'
    })
    return output

# The code expects the document to contains exactly one sentence.
document =  'Robots in popular culture are there to remind us of the awesomeness of'\
            'unbound human agency.'
print('document: {0}'.format(document))

# Parse the text
annotations = get_stanford_annotations(document, port=9000,
                                       annotators='tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,depparse')
tokens = annotations['sentences'][0]['tokens']

# Load Stanford CoreNLP's dependency tree into a networkx graph
edges = []
dependencies = {}
for edge in annotations['sentences'][0]['basic-dependencies']:
    edges.append((edge['governor'], edge['dependent']))
    dependencies[(min(edge['governor'], edge['dependent']),
                  max(edge['governor'], edge['dependent']))] = edge

graph = nx.Graph(edges)
#pprint(dependencies)
#print('edges: {0}'.format(edges))

# Find the shortest path
token1 = 'Robots'
token2 = 'awesomeness'
for token in tokens:
    if token1 == token['originalText']:
        token1_index = token['index']
    if token2 == token['originalText']:
        token2_index = token['index']

path = nx.shortest_path(graph, source=token1_index, target=token2_index)
print('path: {0}'.format(path))

for token_id in path:
    token = tokens[token_id-1]
    token_text = token['originalText']
    print('Node {0}\ttoken_text: {1}'.format(token_id,token_text))
```

The output is:

```
document: Robots in popular culture are there to remind us of the awesomeness of unbound human agency.
path: [1, 5, 8, 12]
Node 1  token_text: Robots
Node 5  token_text: are
Node 8  token_text: remind
Node 12 token_text: awesomeness
```

Note that Stanford CoreNLP can be tested online: http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/parser/index.jsp

This answer was tested with Stanford CoreNLP 3.6.0., pycorenlp 0.3.0 and python 3.5 x64 on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.